# Running rake db:setup on server, how to change to production mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Running rake db:setup on server, how to change to production mode?

I am SSH'd into the server (nginx, ubuntu, passenger)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
rake db:setup RAILS_ENV=production
```

Comment: ok it "worked", but getting:Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock'

Comment: @Blankman: in that case, check your `database.yml` settings for the production database. This is a different issue.